# Cocoapods & forked project (AFOauth2Client)

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I have an issue with my podfile. I require AFNetworking 2.0 & a fork of AFOAuth2Client which takes into account changes made in AFNetworking 2.0.

This is my pod file

```
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'AFOAuth2Client’, :git => ‘https://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client.git'
```

The issue is I get an error :

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `AFOAuth2Client’, :git =>
>   ‘https://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client.git`.

The fork has the .podspec file in the repo so I do not know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in Cocoapods, you should open an [issue mentioning this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/)

Meanwhile you could do:

```
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'AFOAuth2Client', :podspec => 'https://raw.github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client/master/AFOAuth2Client.podspec'
```

Note however that you should update the podspec in your fork. The current spec points to the original repo, and lists AFNetworking 1.0 as a dependency.

Comment: I created new issue as you suggested. :